# When training with MAML and Siamese networks, I've encountered issues where the weights aren't updating or the accuracy remains unchanged

Tags: pytorch, siamese-network, maml, meta-learning

I want to train a model for subjective question scoring using ALBERT and a Siamese network, which consists of a bidirectional LSTM and a fully connected layer. During training, I've noticed that the accuracy doesn't increase—it remains unchanged. I suspect that the weights are not updating, possibly due to small gradients causing subtle weight changes. Alternatively, there might be issues with the training strategy, but I'm unsure of the specific reasons.
The following is the accuracy output during training:

[Please click here to view the accuracy image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSyc0.jpg)

The following is my training strategy code:

```
class MetaTask(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, args):
    super(MetaTask, self).__init__()
    self.device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    self.loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    self.update_lr = args.update_lr
    self.meta_lr = args.meta_lr
    self.finetunning_lr = args.finetunning_lr
    self.n_way = args.n_way
    self.k_spt = args.k_spt
    self.k_qry = args.k_qry
    self.task_num = args.task_num
    self.update_step = args.update_step
    self.update_step_test = args.update_step_test
    self.net = SubjectiveGradingModel().to(self.device)
    self.meta_optim = optim.Adam(self.net.parameters(), lr=self.meta_lr)


def forward(self, support_x, support_y, query_x, query_y):
    task_num = len(support_x)
    querysz = len(query_x[0])
    losses_q = [0 for _ in range(self.update_step + 1)]
    corrects = [0 for _ in range(self.update_step + 1)]
    for i in range(task_num):
        self.net.train()
        # 1. run the i-th task and compute loss for k=0
        logits = self.net(support_x[i])
        loss = self.loss_fn(logits, torch.cat(support_y[i], dim=0).long())
        fast_weights = OrderedDict(self.net.named_parameters())
        grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, fast_weights.values(), retain_graph=True)
        fast_weights = OrderedDict(
            (name, param - self.update_lr * grad)
            for ((name, param), grad) in zip(fast_weights.items(), grad)
        )
        # this is the loss and accuracy before first update
        with torch.no_grad():
            self.net.eval()
            logits_q = self.net(query_x[i])
            loss_q = self.loss_fn(logits_q, torch.cat(query_y[i], dim=0).long())
            losses_q[0] += loss_q
            pred_q = F.softmax(logits_q, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)
            correct = torch.eq(pred_q, torch.cat(query_y[i], dim=0).long()).sum().item()
            corrects[0] = corrects[0] + correct

        # this is the loss and accuracy after the first update
        with torch.no_grad():
            self.net.eval()
            self.net.load_state_dict(fast_weights, strict=False)
            logits_q = self.net(query_x[i])
            loss_q = self.loss_fn(logits_q, torch.cat(query_y[i], dim=0).long())
            losses_q[1] += loss_q

            pred_q = F.softmax(logits_q, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)
            correct = torch.eq(pred_q, torch.cat(query_y[i], dim=0).long()).sum().item()
            corrects[1] = corrects[1] + correct
        self.net.train()
        for k in range(1, self.update_step):
            # 1. run the i-th task and compute loss for k=1~K-1
            self.net.load_state_dict(fast_weights, strict=False)
            logits = self.net(support_x[i])
            loss = self.loss_fn(logits, torch.cat(support_y[i], dim=0).long())
            # 2. compute grad on theta_pi
            fast_weights = OrderedDict(self.net.named_parameters())
            grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, fast_weights.values(), retain_graph=True)
            # 3. theta_pi = theta_pi - train_lr * grad
            fast_weights = OrderedDict(
                (name, param - self.update_lr * grad)
                for ((name, param), grad) in zip(fast_weights.items(), grad)
            )
            self.net.load_state_dict(fast_weights, strict=False)
            logits_q = self.net(query_x[i])
            # loss_q will be overwritten and just keep the loss_q on last update step.
            loss_q = self.loss_fn(logits_q, torch.cat(query_y[i], dim=0).long())
            losses_q[k + 1] += loss_q

            with torch.no_grad():
                pred_q = F.softmax(logits_q, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)
                correct = torch.eq(pred_q, torch.cat(query_y[i], dim=0).long()).sum().item()  # convert to numpy
                corrects[k + 1] = corrects[k + 1] + correct

    loss_q = losses_q[-1] / task_num
    # optimize theta parameters
    self.meta_optim.zero_grad()
    loss_q.backward(retain_graph=True)
    # print('meta update')
    self.meta_optim.step()
    accs = np.array(corrects) / (querysz * task_num)
    return accs
```

Below is my model.

```
class SubjectiveGradingModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, hidden_size=384):
    super(SubjectiveGradingModel, self).__init__()

    self.bert = AlbertModel.from_pretrained('src/datamoudle/model/albert_chinese_small')
    self.siamese_network = Siamese(max_length=378, embedding_size=hidden_size)


def forward(self, input_data ,weights=None):

    input_ids_list = [item['input_ids'].squeeze(0).squeeze(0) for item in input_data]
    token_type_ids_list = [item['token_type_ids'].squeeze(0).squeeze(0) for item in input_data]
    attention_mask_list = [item['attention_mask'].squeeze(0).squeeze(0) for item in input_data]
    answer_input_ids_list = [item['answer_input_ids'].squeeze(0).squeeze(0) for item in input_data]
    answer_token_type_ids_list = [item['answer_token_type_ids'].squeeze(0).squeeze(0) for item in input_data]
    answer_attention_mask_list = [item['answer_attention_mask'].squeeze(0).squeeze(0) for item in input_data]

    input_ids = torch.stack(input_ids_list)
    token_type_ids = torch.stack(token_type_ids_list)
    attention_mask = torch.stack(attention_mask_list)
    answer_input_ids = torch.stack(answer_input_ids_list)
    answer_token_type_ids = torch.stack(answer_token_type_ids_list)
    answer_attention_mask = torch.stack(answer_attention_mask_list)


    outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    pooled_output = outputs.last_hidden_state
    cls_output = outputs.pooler_output
    outputs_answer = self.bert(input_ids=answer_input_ids, token_type_ids=answer_token_type_ids, attention_mask=answer_attention_mask)
    pooled_output_answer = outputs_answer.last_hidden_state
    cls_output_answer = outputs_answer.pooler_output

    siamese_output = self.siamese_network(pooled_output, pooled_output_answer, cls_output, cls_output_answer)

    return siamese_output
```

Below is the siamese network.

```
class LSTMEncoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, embed_size, hidden_size, num_layers, bidir, dropout):
    super(LSTMEncoder, self).__init__()
    self.embed_size = embed_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.bidir = bidir
    if self.bidir:
        self.direction = 2
    else: self.direction = 1
    self.dropout = dropout
    self.device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=self.embed_size, hidden_size=self.hidden_size, dropout=self.dropout,
                        num_layers=self.num_layers, bidirectional=self.bidir)

def initHiddenCell(self, batch_size):
    rand_hidden = Variable(torch.randn(self.direction * self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size, requires_grad=True)).to(self.device)
    rand_cell = Variable(torch.randn(self.direction * self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size, requires_grad=True)).to(self.device)
    return rand_hidden, rand_cell

def forward(self, input, hidden, cell):
    output, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(input, (hidden, cell))
    return output, hidden, cell
class Siamese(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, max_length, embedding_size):
        super(Siamese, self).__init__()
        self.max_length = max_length

        self.encoder = LSTMEncoder(embed_size=embedding_size, hidden_size=64, num_layers=1, bidir=True,dropout=0.2)

        self.input_dim = 5 * self.encoder.direction * self.encoder.hidden_size

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(896, self.input_dim // 2),
            nn.Linear(self.input_dim // 2, 9)
        )

    def forward(self, student_answer_emb, model_answer_emb, v1, v2):

        h1, c1 = self.encoder.initHiddenCell(batch_size=student_answer_emb.size(0))
        h2, c2 = self.encoder.initHiddenCell(batch_size=model_answer_emb.size(0))

        _, h1, c1 = self.encoder(student_answer_emb.permute(1, 0, 2), h1, c1)
        _, h2, c2 = self.encoder(model_answer_emb.permute(1, 0, 2), h2, c2)

        lstm_v1 = h1[-1, :, :]
        lstm_v2 = h2[-1, :, :]

        features = torch.cat((v1,  v2, lstm_v1, lstm_v2), 1)

        output = self.classifier(features)
        output = F.softmax(output, dim=1)
        return output
```